# revert one merge/push which has many pulls

Tags: git

I have a main repository [A] with the main software. I created a clone (adding modules to this software, not meant for anyone else consuming [A]), into another repository [B] which consumes (PULL) updates of [A]. Therefore [B] has multiple pulls and merges along the way from [A].

Now recently I decided to bugfix (37173bc) some issue in [B] in the codebase of [A] and wanted to push just that one commit back to [A]. I assumed it would just push that one commit, but I accidently pushed everything from [B] to [A].

To make matters worse, at first I didn't notice the problem back in [A], I just noticed that the root solution file was renamed and decided to renamte it back in [A] and commited that fix (579dcb6) - also pulling that one back to [B].

At that point I noticed I've really f**ed up the repos :). I wanted to revert the last couple of commits to [A], but...

That one mistaken merge/push/commit from [B] to [A] is actually many commits now in [A] and I can't just revert/reset HEAD~5, but have somehow get rid of all of the other commits from [B] which now appear in [A].

Up to 5b7760d (blue line) all cyan commits where to [A]. From that point on all progress within [A] is suddenly shown on the purple line.

So I want to REMOVE ALL CYAN COMMITS AFTER 5b7760d from [A], effectively killing all traces from any [B] in [A]. Since I am the only one using the repos, I'm fine with doing a rebase afterward.

Any help would be greatly apprechiated!

[image]

Comment: http://justinhileman.info/article/git-pretty/ < may be worth looking at since it seems that you really do have a bit of a mess on your hands, and it may be best to just let it be and fix from where you're at.

Comment: problem is - if I delete the additional modules from [A] they will also get deleted at [B] on next PULL. How can I avoid that?

Comment: So you're telling me that this is uncommitted?  Are any of the branches you've merged in upstream?

Comment: Untortunately both [A] and [B] are currently identical (but should not be), and both are commited upstream/origin. So I have no uncommitted changes locally.

Answer (score 0):

I just arrived at home and here I luckily had a version of [A] before the merge from [B]. So I thought I'd just try `git push -f origin master` and it seems to have reverted all changes from [B] in repo [A]!! Yeah! I'll have to see what this means for [B] tomorrow in the office, but at least [A] is clean again! So what do we learn - sometimes it's a good idea to keep a copy of the local repo around before trying new stuff with the repo :)

Comment: the [B] repo did not care about my last action at all, so my above solution works just great! would be interesting to know if there was a way to pull a version just like the one I had at home from [A] and do what I did above